# Output of a Multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I am trying to understand the output of the below code .As per my understanding the output may be different for First and Second thread.But when I have executed the below code many times I am still getting the same value for both thread.Can someone please throw some light whether I am wrong or right.

```
package com.vikash.Threading;

public class ThreadLocalExample {

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();
        D d=new D();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //threadLocal.set( (int) (Math.random() * 100D) );
            d.setX( (int) (Math.random() * 100D) );
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+threadLocal.get());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+d.getX());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+threadLocal.get());
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+d.getX());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyRunnable sharedRunnableInstance = new MyRunnable();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(sharedRunnableInstance);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(sharedRunnableInstance);

        thread1.start();thread1.setName("First");
        thread2.start();thread2.setName("Second");;

        thread1.join(); //wait for thread 1 to terminate
        thread2.join(); //wait for thread 2 to terminate
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vikash: the code lacks synchronization, which means that, formally, the results are not completely specified. In other words, you have no guarantees as to what the results are going to be. However, you also don't have any guarantees that you *are* going to see different results if you run it multiple times. It might happen that in your specific system, in your specific JVM version, Java compiler, etc, it *might* happen that you will always see the same results. But again: formally speaking (ie, according to the JVM specs) your code isn't guaranteed any specific results.

Comment: @Vikash: the only thing you can "prove" to yourself by running multiple times is: if you see different results, you have *evidence* of the lack of synchronization. However, if you run multiple times and always see the same results, you don't have any kind of evidence. It's really hard to test synchronization issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not synchronizing on `d`, so what happens is thread 1 sets X value, then thread 2 sets x value, then thread 1 prints value that was already reset by thread 2. Synchronize block makes sure the correct value is printed

```
synchronized (d) {
    d.setX((int) (Math.random() * 100D));
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + d.getX());
}
```

Comment: (damn, lost my comment accidentally while trying to add more text; rewriting it) The field `d` is initialized before both threads are started, so there's a happens-before relationship here. Nothing ever changes the field `d` after that initialization. This means that both threads are guaranteed to read the field `d` correctly initialized. Adding `volatile` doesn't change anything: the only thing volatile does is establish happens-before relationships of writes to the volatile field followed by reads of the same volatile field.

Comment: @BrunoReis you are right, the volatile is not enough here. Edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out